# titanium android notification must open specific window

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm creating an Android app using Titanium appcelerator(using alloy), I create a status bar notification, the issue is when the notification appears, I want open a specific window and pass it some data when the user taps the notification, so my code is:

```
// Intent object to launch the application
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action : Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
    flags : Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,
    url : "window.js"
});
intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.putExtra("id", "10");
var activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
// Create a PendingIntent to tie together the Activity and Intent
var pending = Titanium.Android.createPendingIntent({
    activity : activity,
    intent : intent,
    type : Ti.Android.PENDING_INTENT_FOR_ACTIVITY,
    flags : Titanium.Android.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
});

// Create the notification
var notification = Titanium.Android.createNotification({
    // icon is passed as an Android resource ID -- see Ti.App.Android.R.
    icon : Ti.App.Android.R.drawable.appicon,
    contentTitle : 'Something Happened',
    contentText : 'Click to return to the application.',
    contentIntent : pending,
    flags : Ti.Android.ACTION_DEFAULT | Ti.Android.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Ti.Android.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS
});
// Send the notification.
Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

when the user taps the notification, indeed, the app comes to front, but in the same window where was left, not exactly the wanted window.

I'm almost there, give me a little push.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here I go answering my own question, I wasted 2 full days performing this, I'm starting to think that there is no a big community of titanium devs, anyway some importants points here:

1. There is no an Alloy example related to android notification
   status bar, all the examples are classic titanium application, so I
   had to guess where should put my activity js file.
2. Special attention with intent flags, I screwed up with that. I used
   `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`, according with [android official 
   documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED), it could sound properly, but in titanium it does not 
   work. I avoid use action for this case, this Intent only has `flags` and 
   `url` attributes.
3. The same way, pending intent should only have `activity` and `flags` 
   attributes.

The code working in Titanium 3.4.0.GA would be:

```
// Intent object to launch the application
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    flags :  Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP,
    url: "videocomplete.js"
});
intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.putExtra("id", "10");
var activity = Ti.Android.currentActivity;
// Create a PendingIntent to tie together the Activity and Intent
var pending = Titanium.Android.createPendingIntent({
    intent : intent,
    flags : Titanium.Android.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
});

// Create the notification
var notification = Titanium.Android.createNotification({
    // icon is passed as an Android resource ID -- see Ti.App.Android.R.
    icon : Ti.App.Android.R.drawable.appicon,
    contentTitle : 'Something Happened',
    contentText : 'Click to return to the application.',
    contentIntent : pending,
    flags : Ti.Android.ACTION_DEFAULT | Ti.Android.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Ti.Android.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS
});
// Send the notification.
Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Important declaring the activity in tiapp.xml, this config must be inside of android node

```
<activities>
        <activity url="youractivityfile.js">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </activities>
```

**Important, if you are using alloy your activity js file has to be in

> app > assets > android

from there when the user taps the notification the code in that file will be executed.**

Comment: If you are using alloy , you can also keep your activity js file in lib folder. Just create a lib folder in app directory.